# Tikz Graph without using a tikz document class

Tags: tikz-pgf, document-classes, tikz-trees, trees, tikz-qtree

The following solution is absolutely perfect for my purposes, but I noticed that it requires `\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}`.  Is there a way to get the same result with a standard `\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsart}` document class?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,arrows.meta}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth]    
\graph  [tree layout, grow=down]{
  1 <- 2 <- {
    3 <- {
      5 <- {10,11,12}, 6 <- {13,14}, 7 <- {,15}
    }, 
    4 <- {,/}
  };   
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just put `\usepackage{tikz}` in your preamble.

Comment: @Sigur 36 seconds... ;).

Comment: @Sigur No. Just very, very unusual... I'm always posting things only to find out somebody posted in the meantime!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`standalone` is a special class for developing diagrams etc. separately from your main file. If you want all the code in your main file, you just need to include the relevant packages in your ordinary preamble. For example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,arrows.meta}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
```

## EDIT

If you do not wish to use LuaTeX for your main document, you have a couple of options.

### Option 1

Avoid use of the graph-drawing libraries altogether. For example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      edge={{Stealth[]}-},
    }
    [1
      [2
        [3
          [5
            [10
            ]
            [11
            ]
            [12
            ]
          ]
          [6
            [13
            ]
            [14
            ]
          ]
          [7
            [15
            ]
          ]
        ]
        [4
          [, phantom
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

will produce

[image: tree without graphs]

and can be compiled with your choice of engine. (I used pdfTeX for the example above but you can take your pick.)

### Option 2

Use LuaTeX to compile the graph using the `standalone` class (or any other class you prefer) and then use `graphicx` to include the compiled image into your main document with `\includegraphics{}`.

Comment: Good to know that I don't need that doc class, but I'm getting the error `n...LuaTeX to use the graph drawing library`, which I assume is suggesting I need to use LuaTeX.  My question is:  Could using this compile method potential cause errors in other parts of the document?

Comment: @user67471 Yes. You need LuaTeX to use the graph drawing libraries of TiKZ. You can use other libraries and the main packages etc. with other engines, but the graph-drawing facilities depend on Lua. Is that a problem? If so, there might be another way to draw the diagram...

Comment: @user67471 I've edited my answer to outline a couple of options if you prefer to avoid the use of LuaTeX for some reason.

Comment: It turns out that LuaLaTeX has kept everything as it should be.  That said, it's good to know the other way just in case. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @user67471 `forest` is always a good package to know, even if you don't need it for this ;).